# Button "Register" does not work, after clicking it

Tags: java, android, xml

Starting my program, writing all data, but button Register does not work (there sign on Russian). Also does not work any mistakes checker (like password length and other) I don't know where is the root of the problem. I made everything like in guide.

activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35sp"


            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="55sp"

            >

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/slogan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@string/undermain"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp">

        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/name_reg"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/email_reg_and_login"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/password_reg"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@string/register_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:iconTint="#d4a8fd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_mainscreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@string/login_mainscreen"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp">


        </TextView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:visibility="invisible" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is register.
Register.java

```
package com.example.kanlane;

import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Переменные
    EditText mName, mEmail, mPassword;
    Button mRegisterBtn;
    TextView mLoginbtn;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);



        //Переменные.
        mName = findViewById(R.id.Name);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
        mLoginbtn = findViewById(R.id.login_mainscreen);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }


        //Скрывает ненужные панели.
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }






        //Кнопка регистрации.
        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                final String Name = mName.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Введите почту...");
                    return;

                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mEmail.setError("Введите пароль...");
                    return;

                }

                if(password.length() < 8 ){
                    mPassword.setError("Пароль должен состоять из 8-ми символов.");

                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                //Регистрация пользователя.
                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Пользователь зарегистрирован.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Произошла ошибка, зарегистрируйтесь заново."
                            + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });







    }
    //Скрывает ненужные панели.
    public static void setWindowFlag (AppCompatActivity activity,final int bits, boolean on){
        Window win = activity.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }
}
```

Here is my:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kanlane">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kanlane">
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.kanlane;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        //Для полноэкранного режима и скрывания шапки.
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

    }

    //Для полноэкранного режима и скрывания шапки.
    public static void setWindowFlag(AppCompatActivity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
        Window win = activity.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }

}
```

Help me please.

Comment: Look in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);`. Seems like `MainActivity` might actually be starting, but you can't tell 'cause it looks exactly like `Register`. You presumably meant to set `MainActivity`'s own separate layout there; e.g., `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.